# upper bound for the sum of trace related to product of two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Given A and B positive definite matrices

The inequality $\sqrt{4tr(AB)}$ $\leq$ $tr(A+B)$ is lower bound for tr(A+B) is there another inequality for the upper bound, i.e. ?? ≥ tr(A+B)?

Comment: Well, $\mathrm{tr}(A+B)=\mathrm{tr}(A)+\mathrm{tr}(B)$ gives a good "upper bound".

Comment: fine, can  I get "upper bound'' that related $trace(A+B)$ to $trace(AB)$